# SQL Server Compact 4.0 Provider is not in list for EF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

My WPF application uses Entity Framework 4.0 with a SQL Server CE database. And I need to have SQL Server CE 4.0 to allow the `@@IDENTITY` columns to be server generated.

So I just installed SQL Server Compact 4.0 on my system, but I cannot create a SQL Server CE 4.0 database since its not in the list when I choose a data source from VS2010.

[image]

I wonder why because in the Windows programs list SQL Server CE 4.0 is there :

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the [Visual Studio Tools for SQL Server Compact 4](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html)

Then you get:

[image]